# Shopoware 6: Avoid reloading the page when selecting variants

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How can I avoid that when I select a variant the page is reloaded and jumps to the top of the page?
We have the problem in the mobile view.

Thanks for your help.

Unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution yet.